# Is uploading a dead person's picture on social media allowed?

Tags: sunni, death, photos

A few months ago, my cousin's brother died and then my other cousins started uploading his pictures on social media (Facebook), attaching them with their pictures.

My question is, is this behavior allowed in Islam?

Comment: Thankz but someone told me that this is a sin...

Answer (score 0):

الشيخ أ.د. عبدالعزيز الفوزان
He said it is not good to keep dead person photo in social media because it makes people sad and make people feeling sad whenever they look to the photos, but if you don't feel sad whenever you look to his photo just for pray for him there is no problem or to show it to his sibling but it is prefer not to keep it .